# Can't upload file into AWS - Missing region error in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

While re-creating a typical online book store with Rails, I've come across with an error that shows up when I try to upload a picture and a file to the AWS.

Here's the steps I followed until reach this error:

1 - Setting up Amazon Web Services (no problems found)

2 - S3 Storage (no problems found):

a) Added the aws gem file

b) Overrrided the default storage for PaperClip by adding a configuration for PaperClip to my application.rb file [ I want to use a different bucket for each different environment the application runs ]. Here's the code I have:

```
config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
config.paperclip_defaults = { 
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials:{
        bucket: ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
        access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
        secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
}
```

c) Opened the .env to add the S3 credentials to the file. AWS_BUCKET, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

d) Also the added the fields in my form file partial by adding fields for the image and resource.

e) Because the PaperClip requires to validate the content type before we submit, I added simple validations to the Book.rb model as suggested by the PaperClip documentation.

3 - Adding Book Images (and Resources)

I think that everything about my AWS S3 bucket is configured and working, although, when I make the upload of my "book" files by creating a new book in the form, here's the error that I get:

```
Aws::Errors::MissingRegionError in BooksController#create

missing region; use :region option or export region name to ENV['AWS_REGION']
```

This is how my #create on the Books controller:

```
  def create
    @book = current_user.books.new(book_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.save
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @book }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Did you try specifying a region?

Comment: No. I religiously followed the docs I have and there was no indication provided in relation to add some sort of region information. Where and how can I add my correspondent region?

Answer (score 1):

Set `us-east-1` as your region in env variable `AWS_REGION` and specify it in your defaults. I haven't tried this, but see if this solution works. If it does, then find what your region is and set it.

```
config.paperclip_defaults = { 
    storage: :s3,
    s3_region: ENV['AWS_REGION'],
    s3_credentials:{
        bucket: ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
        access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
        secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
```

}

Don't know what your default region is. Change it to the correct region and try. The solution is to identify the issue, not to correct the issue.

Comment: if you set the environment variable then you don't need to specify the option.  Also, you don't know that OP's region is us-east-1 (even though it's the common) so to present that as the authoritative solution is misleading.

Comment: @maxpleaner, thats why I said I did not try the solution since I am not familiar with Ruby. You are correct about region, but my solution was to check if it was indeed the problem.

Comment: @helloV As far as I understood, my region is "eu-west-2" because my bucket says EU (London). Anyway, I added the s3_region: ENV['AWS_REGION'] as you mentioned and on my .env file I added "AWS_REGION=eu-west-2" to the file. Now I receive the following error: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed